# get a forms values via jquery, post to a php script, and have php script process for errors and return value

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form:

```
<form action= 'addperm.php' class = 'addperm' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='user' /><br />
    <input type='radio' name='perm' value='1' CHECKED /> Can view only<br />
<input type='radio' name='perm' value='2' /> Can make changes <br />
<input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
```

I want to know how, without redirecting to another page, I can get these two input values (user and perm), post them to a php script via ajax, and then have the php return the results

Comment: I've gotten how to post the values....but I want to get the php to return the value and also clear the form.

Comment: Without redirecting? A PHP script can both generate a form and handle its submission quite easily. if you mean you want the form data to be submitted without refreshing, that's another matter.

Comment: Post some more pertinent code showing what you've accomplished so far. Then with the code as reference, point out the specific areas where you're having problems.

Comment: without refreshing is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Read the jQuery API documentation for [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "user=" + $('input[name=user]').val() + "&perm=" + $('input[name=perm]:checked').val(),
        success: function(msg){
            // msg is your content
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

some.php

```
echo json_encode(array($_POST['user'],$_POST['perm']));
```

I wouldn't take my syntax at face value, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Download jQuery from http://jquery.com

Include it in the head of your page as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the src to whatever the name of the file you downloaded is.

Then also in the head of your page paste this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addperm').submit(function(){
        var query = 'perm='+$('#perm').val()+'&user='+$('#user').val(); 
            $.post("addperm.php", query, function(response){
                alert(response);
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

To make this work you are going to have to change your HTML to this:

```
<form action= 'addperm.php' class = 'addperm' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='user' id='user' /><br />
<input type='radio' name='perm' value='1' id='perm' CHECKED /> Can view only<br />
<input type='radio' name='perm' value='2' id='perm' /> Can make changes <br />
<input type='submit' value='Add'>
</form>
```

I havent tested it yet, but it should work.